# Coin operated anti alien vehicle cannon in a movie or show?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I vaguely remember seeing a *Men in Black* styled movie where two guys were sitting in an "anti alien artillery gun vehicle" and had to insert coins into the vehicle to fire the gun. I also remember they didn't quite kill one and had to go over to the spaceship and when they went into it, there was a whole boxing ring fight scene. It's a little *Independence Day*-ish.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a nice general description but can you remember anymore about this? If so please [edit] those details into your question. For example, when did you watch this? Was it new at the time? Can you remember any of the overarching plot i.e. why were there aliens? Why were they attacking? Who were the people defending? What did the aliens look like? What did the spaceship look like? etc.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Futurama's [Raiders of the Lost Arcade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthology_of_Interest_II#Raiders_of_the_Lost_Arcade) - though I don't remember a boxing ring.